# Scaling gltf model, what is wrong?

Tags: math, matrix, rust, graphics, gltf

I want to scale the *mesh* in a gltf model. i.e. the actual vertex data, while keeping the animations.

Before me editing the gltf file, we have the following math model, let A be the animation matrix, i/e/ the blended matrix obtained after multiplying and adding the animation and ibm matrices. Let S be the scaling matrix.

Trivially, at rendering time doing SAx for every x in the shader will yield the scaled model.

Now, if you scale x before applying the transformation, your input is now Sx. We thus want a matrix B such that

SAx = BSx => B = SAS^-1.

Which is trivially ttrue since BSx = SAS^-1Sx = SAx.

For any animation matrix A this is what SAS^-1 looks like:

```
⎡A₀₀  A₀₁  A₀₂  s⋅A₀₃⎤
⎢                    ⎥
⎢A₁₀  A₁₁  A₁₂  s⋅A₁₃⎥
⎢                    ⎥
⎢A₂₀  A₂₁  A₂₂  s⋅A₂₃⎥
⎢                    ⎥
⎢A₃₀  A₃₁  A₃₂       ⎥
⎢───  ───  ───   A₃₃ ⎥
⎣ s    s    s        ⎦
```

But the bottom row is (0, 0, 0, 1), so basically we can ignore all but the last column of the matrix.

This mathematical model is telling me that if I scale down the translation component of my animation data AND my mesh data, I should be fine.

To that effect I wrote this functions in rust (the implementation is irrelevant)

```rust
    for animation in &gltf.animations
    {
        scale_animation(0.02, &animation, &gltf);
    }

    for skin in &gltf.skins
    {
        scale_skin(0.02, &skin, &gltf);
    }

    scale_nodes(0.02, &mut gltf);

    for mesh in &gltf.meshes
    {
        scale_mesh(0.02, &mesh, &gltf);
    }
```

All these do is scale down the translation component of the respective data, for example:

```rust
fn scale_skin(scale : f32, skin : &Skin, gltf : &Gltf)
{
    let mat_data =
        gltf.data_from_accessor::<Mat4>(
            skin.inverse_bind_matrices);

    for mat in mat_data
    {
        let mut slice =
            mat.slice_mut((0, 0), (3,4));

        slice *= scale;
    }
}
```

These all work and do what they should I tested. The thing is, doing all these 4 operations yields this result:

[image]

But If I don't scale the mesh data and only scale the animation data, I get this:

[image]

Which is correct. But of course if I delete the animation data from the gltf json, the model is back up to humongous size.

I don't understand where my math is failing. It's not an implementation bug, I am thinking about something wrong.

TL;DR, if I scale down the mesh data, what transformation must I apply to my animation data to keep the animations?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever runs into this issue.

Turns out my math was fine. I was making the mistake of multiplying the whole IBM matrix instead of just the scaling components. I.e. I was applying the same transformation twice.